# Php login page issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

In simple login page,working correctly.For example,if user insert his id and password then he will be logged in-this is working fine.
**Problem is**,if he reloads the url in browser of **loggedin.php** i.e. **www.example.com/login**(home page) and **www.example.com/loggedin.php** (next script or url in browser)then it fetched all id password stored in database.
What i want: If he reloads url after login,then it must not fetch other person user id and on reloading it must connect to home page i.e. **www.example.com/login** Please check,where i'm missing it.
Code:

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect user if logged in, you can do this by simply adding this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])){
   header('location: home.php');
   exit();
}
```

Add this code just after `session_start();`

Comment: Want to redirect If in logged in,he reloads the url then only.Can i do this with your code?How?

Comment: This code will redirect the user if he is logged in and tries to reload the page.

Comment: Ok @madforstrenght i understand what you say.

Comment: Just for query,if this won't be login page,consider a simple search engine result display page,then how to connect that to home page if someone reloads the url

Comment: I dont think you can do that on refresh, for example if a user presses `F5` on a search result page than all the header variables will again be posted.

Comment: Ok madforstrength,then if user reloads url then header variables will be posted,now why all queires for example user search for cat and on relaods all db stored data about dog to elephant fetched?Why not only of cat?

Comment: Their must be something in the code, you need to show me the code for search.

Comment: Please help it is also necessary.check:// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$image = $_POST['image'];

$sql = " SELECT pagesky FROM `searchengine` WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%$image%' ";

if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 
        echo '<a href='. $row["pagesky"] .' > <div class="ws14"><span class="city"><br>' . $row['pagesky'] . '</br></span></div></a>';  
   }

$conn->close();

?>

Comment: You are using wildcard in query `%$image%` thats why when it comes empty it shows all the records. If you don't want this behavior then you can simply redirect users if image variable is not coming

Comment: if (!isset($_POST['image']) || empty($_POST['image'])){
 header('location: home.php');
 exit();
}